# JavaScript inline code and including .js file

Tags: javascript

What is the difference if i include java script in normal HTML  tag and include .js file in my page ??

Comment: Difference in what regard exactly?

Answer (score 5):

Not much. It is recommended that you move your JavaScript and CSS to external files mainly because browsers are able to cache these files between different requests. This advantage is most evident when your site makes use of dynamic content, and therefore the browser cannot retrieve the HTML from the cache.

Comment: Thanky you very much to all of you

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Daniel, but also for reusability. By separating the javascript file you can then include it in multiple pages by referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

- Having JS in a file makes it more modular so you can reuse that code over a number of pages.
- Since its a different file means that you can use 1 download stream for the HTML and 1 for the JS making the page load a little quicker.
- You can also minify and obstificate JS when it is in another file making it quicker to download.

Answer (score 1):

If you have javascript code in head element and if will be executed before your page is rendered in the browser, then it will degrade the user experience in some browsers.

If you are using javascript code inline, and in body using script tag, it will be executed as soon as it encountered. Again, it will delay loading of your page after that specific tag.

It is a better practice to:

1. Separate it in .js file
2. Add the script reference at the end of file

Answer (score 1):

If you include the .js files inside the `<head>` tag, the page will only load after those files load. This is why sometimes it's better to include them just before .

Otherwise, as far as i know, using `<script src=...>` is just semantic separation.